# How to remove namespace from WEB API request & response XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

[image]

I want to remove highlighted node from WEB API request and response.
Below are the class Models used in web api

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class ValidateRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Client_Code { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ClientValidateNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class ValidateResponse
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to remove highlighted node from WEB API request and response.
> Below are the class Models used in web api

To achieve this function, first you need to create a class that inherits from `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter`:

```
public class XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace : XmlSerializerOutputFormatter
        {
            protected override void Serialize(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, XmlWriter xmlWriter, object value)
            {
                //applying "empty" namespace will produce no namespaces
                var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                emptyNamespaces.Add("", "any-non-empty-string");
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value, emptyNamespaces);
            }
        }
```

Then, add the following service in `ConfigureServices` in startup.cs:

```
 services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace());
    }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

In api method:

```
   [Produces("application/xml")]
    public IActionResult GetXml(ValidateRequest request)
    {
        ValidateResponse response = new ValidateResponse()
        {
            Amount = 100,
            ClientValidateNo = request.ClientValidateNo,
            Client_Code = request.Client_Code,
            DepositorCity = "aaa",
            DepositorName = "das",
            DepositorState = "sadasd",
            Status = "fasfas"
        };
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

The test result:

[image]